# AJAX-loaded page gives empty $_GET

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Pages loaded via AJAX methods. index.php is the base page, profile.php is the page loaded

jQuery: ("post" nothing to do with HTML request)

```
$('<a/>', {href: '?userID='+post['userID']+'#profile'}).text(post['firstName']+' '+post['lastName'])
```

HTML:

```
<a href="?userID=1#profile">Firstname Lastname</a>
```

Raw URL (after click)

```
http://########/#####/index.php?userID=1#home
```

$_GET print_r on profile.php:

```
Array ()
```

By request; the ajax load javascript (index.php):

```
    //AJAX page loading

        $(document).ready(function(){

            //Default page
            if(!window.location.hash)
                window.location.hash = '#home';

            //Check page reference
            checkURL();

            //Update nav
            $('#main-nav li').on("click", function (){
                $('#main-nav li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');

                //Assign each link a new onclick event, using their own hash as a parameter
                checkURL(this.hash);    
            });

            //check for a change in the URL every 250 ms to detect if the history buttons have been used
            setInterval("checkURL()",250);  
        });

        //Store the current URL hash
        var lasturl=""; 

        function checkURL(hash){
            if(!hash)

                //if no parameter is provided, use the hash value from the current address
                hash=window.location.hash;
            if(hash != lasturl) { 

                //If hash changed, update current hash and load new one
                lasturl=hash;
                loadPage(hash);
            }

        }

        function loadPage(url) {

            //Adjust page name
            url=url.replace('#','');   
            url=url+'.php';

            //AJAX load page contents in to main content div
            $('#content').load(url);
        }
```

Comment: Where in your code do you load `profile.php`?

Comment: it's in the index.php document.ready function. It's pretty long, but the page loading works fine (apart from aforementioned problem).

Comment: We need to see the part where the ajax request is sent.

Comment: So does your URL looks like in `loadPage`? It seems to me that you are removing the `#` and adding `.php`, which would give `profile.php`. There is not query string in there, it is normal that $_GET` is empty.

Comment: That is only for the .load() function, which needs a file to point to in order to pull its contents. i have a page called "profile.php". What the link does is add `?userID=1` before the fragment, essentially making the server request; `index.php?userID=1`. I am new to AJAX so I am not sure if the linked file (profile.php) can access the GET request for the base file (index.php)...but then how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Create global storage on root page (index.php).
2. Set vars in storage instead of using $_GET.
3. Access vars from child pages.

Example:

index.php (Javascript)

```
if (typeof(window.storage) === 'undefined') {
    window.storagePV = {};
}

$('#nav-profile').click(function() {
    window.storage.userID = <?php echo "$_SESSION[userID]"; ?>;
});
```

accessing userID to view the user's profile page

```
var userID = window.storage.userID
```